# What should be the C# equivalent of Rust's Box<> type?

Tags: c#, rust, smart-pointers

I am translating Rust code into C#.

Rust has some type called `Box<>` which is said to be C++'s equivalent of smart pointers.

What should be the C# equivalent of Rust's `Box<>` type?

Comment: C# is garbage-collected, it’d just be a normal object (reference) in almost every case.

Comment: [Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) say nothing about ‘smart pointers’. They do say it _Allocates memory on the heap and then places x into it._ so the equivalent is.. a `class`

Comment: Well, to "box" a value type in C#, you'd create an `object` variable and assign the value to it. That creates a _reference_ to the value somewhere in memory. But it depends on what you are _doing_ with the boxed variable in Rust to know more than that.

Comment: Wen translating code rarely is it a good idea to start mapping every type and variable 1:1, instead look at what the code does and reimplement it in the target language.

Comment: One thing to remember is that even though there may be something fairly close to a `Box` in Rust, what you would do in good or reasonable practice differs greatly between a garbage-collected and non-garbage-collected language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that there isn't an exactly-equivalent type.

`Box` is used to put a value on the heap.  There are several reasons why you would want to do that, but that's all it does.

In C#, reference types always point to a heap allocation.  "Boxing" is therefore pointless on reference types, as they are already effectively boxed.

C# value types are instead allocated directly, either on the stack or directly inside an object's heap allocation if used as a non-static class field.  You can box a C# value type by casting it to a compatible reference type: either `object` or an interface type implemented by the value type.

However, reference types in C# are not just boxed, they also have *shared ownership* as well as *shared mutability* and so C# reference types are closer to the Rust types that implement those behaviors, such as `Rc<RefCell<T>>` or `Arc<Mutex<T>>`, though there are still very relevant semantic differences between those types and C# reference types (`Rc<_>` can't be sent to other threads, `Arc<Mutex<_>>` has to be locked to access the inner value, both `Rc` and `Arc` can create reference cycles that could cause a memory leak, etc.).  Shared mutability in particular requires some kind of synchronization/atomicity to even pass the Rust compiler, where C# has no problem letting you create data races.

---

In other words, you need to look at *why* the value is boxed.

- Is it to enable polymorphism on a set of heterogeneous values (`Box<dyn _>`)?  Just use C# interfaces.
- Is it to enable a recursive structure?  Just use C# classes, which can self-recurse without issue.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
public class Box<T>(T val) {
    public T _val = val;
}
```

Comment: An explanation will be helpful here. As shown, this answer does pretty much nothing.